# как получить желаемый массив

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, join, drupal7

Здравствуйте пытаюсь получить массив из объеденных таблиц, но не получается не знаю    что уже делать вот мой код.

```html
$query = db_select('webform_submitted_data', 'wsd');
            $query->leftJoin('webform_component', 'wc', 'wsd.cid = wc.cid');
            $query->leftJoin('webform_submissions', 'ws', 'wsd.sid = ws.sid');
            $query->fields('wsd', array('sid', 'cid', 'data'));
            $query->fields('wc', array('form_key', 'cid',));
            $webformSubmittedData = $query->orderBy('sid')->execute();
            
            $submittedData = array(); 
            
            foreach($webformSubmittedData as $data){
            $submittedData[] = array('sid' => $data->sid, $data->form_key => $data->data);
            }
```

результат получается такой

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sid] => 74
            [imya] => Биржан
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 74
        [familiya] => Мусаев
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 74
        [e_mail] => mbmaction@gmail.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 74
        [phone] => 87018001227
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 74
        [birthday] => 1984-12-27
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 74
        [gender] => 10
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 74
        [country] => KZ
    )
```

как получить такой вариант:?

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sid] => 74
            [imya] => Биржан
            [familiya] => Мусаев
            [country] => KZ
            [e_mail] => mail@gmail.com
            и так далее по списку
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [sid] => 75
        [familiya] => Иванов
        [familiya] => Александр
        [country] => KZ
        [e_mail] => mail@gmail.com
    )
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как значения объединить по sid

Comment: `array_merge(...$data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sid - я так понял общее для одной записи массива, если так то можно сделать вот так (взять его за ключ):

```
...
$submittedData = array(); 

foreach($webformSubmittedData as $data){
    $submittedData[ $data->sid ][ $data->form_key ] = $data->data;
}
```

результат должен быть такой

```
[75] => Array
    (
        [familiya] => Иванов
        [familiya] => Александр
        [country] => KZ
        [e_mail] => mail@gmail.com
    )
[76] => Array
    (
...
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо большое Вы меня правильно поняли все работает!